# How to solve "KeyError: '/conv2d_1/kernel:0'"

Tags: tensorflow, kernel, keyerror, openai-gym, pacman

I am trying to use the colab to run the gym package with pacman, since the spec in colab is more powerful than my notebook. This program is successful simulate in Jupyter in my notebook, which using tensorflow 1.14. However, the errors keep appears when I put in google colab to simulate, and I also debug and change  part of the code, so that the code can be used in tensor flow 2.0. Below is my code

```
   #First we import all the necessary libraries
   import numpy as np
   import gym
   import tensorflow as tf
   from tensorflow import keras
   from keras.layers import Flatten, Conv2D, Dense
   #from tensorflow.contrib.layers import Flatten, conv2d, Dense
   from collections import deque, Counter
   import random
   from datetime import datetime

    #Now we define a function called preprocess_observation for preprocessing our input game screen.
    #We reduce the image size and convert the image into greyscale.

    color = np.array([210, 164, 74]).mean()
    def preprocess_observation(obs):
      # Crop and resize the image
      img = obs[1:176:2, ::2]
      # Convert the image to greyscale
      img = img.mean(axis=2)
      # Improve image contrast
      img[img==color] = 0
      # Next we normalize the image from -1 to +1
      img = (img - 128) / 128-1
      return img.reshape(88,80,1)

    #Let us initialize our gym environment

    env = gym.make('MsPacman-v0')
    n_outputs = env.action_space.n
    print(n_outputs)
    print(env.env.get_action_meanings())
    observation = env.reset()
    import tensorflow as tf
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    for i in range(22):
      if i > 20:
        plt.imshow(observation)
        plt.show()
    observation, _, _, _ = env.step(1)

    #Okay, Now we define a function called q_network for building our Q network. We input the game                         state to the Q network 
    #and get the Q values for all the actions in that state.
    #We build Q network with three convolutional layers with same padding followed by a fully connected layer.
    tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()

    def q_network(X, name_scope):

    # Initialize layers
      initializer = tf.compat.v1.keras.initializers.VarianceScaling(scale=2.0)
      with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope(name_scope) as scope:

        # initialize the convolutional layers
        #layer_1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(X, 32, kernel_size=(8,8), stride=4, padding='SAME',                 weights_initializer=initializer)
        layer_1_set = Conv2D(32, (8,8), strides=4, padding="SAME", kernel_initializer=initializer)
        layer_1= layer_1_set(X)
        tf.compat.v1.summary.histogram('layer_1',layer_1)
        #layer_2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(layer_1, 64, kernel_size=(4,4), stride=2, padding='SAME', weights_initializer=initializer)
        layer_2_set = Conv2D(64, (4,4), strides=2, padding="SAME", kernel_initializer=initializer)
        layer_2= layer_2_set(layer_1)
        tf.compat.v1.summary.histogram('layer_2',layer_2)
        #layer_3 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(layer_2, 64, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=1, padding='SAME', weights_initializer=initializer)
        layer_3_set = Conv2D(64, (3,3), strides=1, padding="SAME", kernel_initializer=initializer)
        layer_3= layer_3_set(layer_2)
        tf.compat.v1.summary.histogram('layer_3',layer_3)
        flatten_layer = Flatten()  # instantiate the layer
        flat = flatten_layer(layer_3)  
        fc_set = Dense(128, kernel_initializer=initializer)
        fc=fc_set(flat)
        tf.compat.v1.summary.histogram('fc',fc)

        #Add final output layer
        output_set = Dense(n_outputs, activation= None, kernel_initializer=initializer)
        output= output_set(fc)
        tf.compat.v1.summary.histogram('output',output)
        vars = {v.name[len(scope.name):]: v for v in tf.compat.v1.get_collection(key=tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope=scope.name)}

        #Return both variables and outputs together
        return vars, output

    #Next we define a function called epsilon_greedy for performing epsilon greedy policy. In epsilon greedy policy we either select the best action 
    #with probability 1 - epsilon or a random action with probability epsilon.
    #We use decaying epsilon greedy policy where value of epsilon will be decaying over time 
    #as we don't want to explore forever. So over time our policy will be exploiting only good actions.

    epsilon = 0.5
    eps_min = 0.05
    eps_max = 1.0
    eps_decay_steps = 500000

    def epsilon_greedy(action, step):
        p = np.random.random(1).squeeze()
        epsilon = max(eps_min, eps_max - (eps_max-eps_min) * step/eps_decay_steps)
        if np.random.rand() < epsilon:
            return np.random.randint(n_outputs)
        else:
            return action

    #Now, we initialize our experience replay buffer of length 20000 which holds the experience.
    #We store all the agent's experience i.e (state, action, rewards) in the 
    #experience replay buffer and we sample from this minibatch of experience for training the network.

    buffer_len = 20000
    exp_buffer = deque(maxlen=buffer_len)

   # Now we define our network hyperparameters,


   num_episodes = 800
   batch_size = 48
   input_shape = (None, 88, 80, 1)
   learning_rate = 0.001
   X_shape = (None, 88, 80, 1)
   discount_factor = 0.97

   global_step = 0
   copy_steps = 100
   steps_train = 4
   start_steps = 2000

    logdir = 'logs'
    tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
    import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
    tf.disable_v2_behavior()
    # Now we define the placeholder for our input i.e game state
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=X_shape)
    #X = tf.Variable(tf.float32, tf.ones(shape=X_shape))
    # we define a boolean called in_training_model to toggle the training
    in_training_mode = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)

   # we build our Q network, which takes the input X and generates Q values for all the actions in the state
   mainQ, mainQ_outputs = q_network(X, 'mainQ')

   # similarly we build our target Q network, for policy evaluation
   targetQ, targetQ_outputs = q_network(X, 'targetQ')

    # define the placeholder for our action values
    X_action = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(None,))
    Q_action = tf.reduce_sum(targetQ_outputs * tf.one_hot(X_action, n_outputs), axis=-1, keepdims=True)

   #Copy the primary Q network parameters to the target Q network
   copy_op = [tf.compat.v1.assign(main_name, targetQ[var_name]) for var_name, main_name in        mainQ.items()]
   copy_target_to_main = tf.group(*copy_op)

    #Compute and optimize loss using gradient descent optimizer


    # define a placeholder for our output i.e action
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,1))

    # now we calculate the loss which is the difference between actual value and predicted value
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - Q_action))

    # we use adam optimizer for minimizing the loss
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar('LOSS', loss)
    merge_summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
    file_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir, tf.get_default_graph())
```

Ok up to here, the error come out when i run this cell in colab :

```
   #Copy the primary Q network parameters to the target Q network
   copy_op = [tf.compat.v1.assign(main_name, targetQ[var_name]) for var_name, main_name in mainQ.items()]
   copy_target_to_main = tf.group(*copy_op)
```

The error gives:

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-13-58715282cea8> in <module>()
   ----> 1 copy_op = [tf.compat.v1.assign(main_name, targetQ[var_name]) for var_name, main_name in mainQ.items()]
         2 copy_target_to_main = tf.group(*copy_op)

   <ipython-input-13-58715282cea8> in <listcomp>(.0)
   ----> 1 copy_op = [tf.compat.v1.assign(main_name, targetQ[var_name]) for var_name, main_name in mainQ.items()]
         2 copy_target_to_main = tf.group(*copy_op)

   KeyError: '/conv2d_1/kernel:0'
```

I have two question?
First, how to solve the question that already stated above.

Second, in tensor-flow 2.0 above,the placeholder command is replaced by tf.Variable, i rewrite the code:

```
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=X_shape) to become
    X = tf.Variable(tf.float32, tf.ones(shape=X_shape))
```

and still get error, and i have to use command below:

```
    import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
    tf.disable_v2_behavior()
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=X_shape)
```

but get warning like this:

```
    WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-        packages/tensorflow/python/compat/v2_compat.py:96: disable_resource_variables (from tensorflow.python.ops.variable_scope) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
    Instructions for updating: non-resource variables are not supported in the long term
```

I  doing intensive searching in the Stack overflow website by using keyword, yet i can't find solution. Really looking forward to any advise. Thank you very much.

Comment: The code you provided is very complicated. From a first glance, you can try to print (to files) all the tensor names (dictionary keys) from mainQ and tengetQ and see what is going on there, and whether the same name is present in both cases. After that, you can debug this assign method you use on some smaller toy example with mainQ and targetQ being a small network with couple of variables, to see whether is is doing what is expected

Comment: Ok, thank for your help.I will try it.